# Working SvelteKit server component results in console error

Tags: javascript, typescript, sveltekit, netlify-function

I'm using a `+server.ts` file to mask the path to a Netlify function. While the redirect and the function both work, I still get to see a console error, e.g. when clicking on a link to `/download?get=filename`.

> Error: Not found: /download/

Here's the code for the server component.

```js
// routes/download/+server.ts

import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const GET: RequestHandler = async () => {
    const options: ResponseInit = {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            location: '/.netlify/functions/download'
        }
    };

    return new Response(null, options);
};
```

I'd love to get rid of the client error, but I'm not sure what causes this.

Comment: Can you try this route => routes/api/download/+server.ts

Comment: I tried to replicate it but I couldn't get a 404 nor such log message. Please, try by creating a minimal reproducible code. Is this error shown in a special place or after some code (like a fetch or something)?